# sharing docker image without docker hub or any such service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry, docker-image

I am new to docker, I was wondering how can I share my docker image with others without posting it on docker hub or any thing?

Is there any way to share image with others and later they can build the same image and run the dockerised application in their pc?

Answer (score 1):

some solutions

1. you can give the source code and the dockerfile to someone, he will be able to build the image himself.
2. you can build it yourself , host the image on a private registry. really easy : https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/
3. use "docker save" to export an image as a tar file and later "docker load" it.
   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

Answer (score 0):

You can use
$docker export <container_name> <tar_filename.tar>

Share the tar file

The person with whom the tar file has been shared can create container by

$docker import <tar_filename.tar>

Make sure that underlying Docker version is same to avoid unnecessary compatibility  problems